# How can I get multiple daily temperature highs through NOAA climate data API with just one AJAX request?

Tags: javascript, noaa

I am trying to look up the temperature highs (datatype = TMAX) for each day within a range of dates. I am using Th NOAA climate data (v2).  Right now I am sending one separate AJAX request for each day. It takes a long time because you can only send five AJAX requests per second. Is there a way that I can get the whole list all at once? Does multiday minimum temperature (MDTN) do that? My ultimate goal is to create a web app where people can get graphic representations of local climate trends. I would like to do it using front-end JavaScript.

EDIT: Documentation: https://www.ncdc.noaa.gov/cdo-web/webservices/v2#data

Comment: `Is there a way that I can get the whole list all at once?` - does the API you use have some sort of *documentation* which you can refer to? a startdate and enddate parameter for instance

Comment: https://www.ncdc.noaa.gov/cdo-web/webservices/v2#data

Comment: Using a date range still only returns one temperature high. The documentation is fairly thorough, but still a bit mysterious. I have read it and put it to work. :)

Comment: perhaps you're not *processing* the received information correctly - but without a single line of code, it's hard to tell what you are or are not doing

Answer (score 0):

The example URL in the documentation for retrieving daily summaries gives only summary information for the whole date range, like total precipitation, temperature high, and temperature low. The example is only for one day, but if you to extend it to more than one day, you still only get summary information, for example:

https://www.ncdc.noaa.gov/cdo-web/api/v2/data?datasetid=GHCND&locationid=ZIP:28801&startdate=2010-05-01&enddate=2010-05-10

If you want an array of values for each separate day, then you have to include parameters: *datatypeid* and *limit*. This will give you a list of temperatures for each day in the range, for example:

&datatypeid=TMAX&limit=1000